# Program stopped working after creating a .jar file with Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, executable-jar

I made a simple Swing application with some database connectivity, using Notepad++ and executing it from the command prompt. It was executing perfectly.

Then I copied all of the code to Netbeans and tried to build to main project, in order to package my application as a .jar file.

A .jar file was created successfully, but when I tried to run it, it did not execute properly. For example, I had a button in my application that displays all records present in the database. It worked when I executed from the command prompt, but when the .jar file was executed, there was no response.

Comment: Would you like to buy a vowel?

Comment: @kaka09, here on SO we're pretty used to normal english grammar, the use of the shift key and paragraphs. Could you please rewrite the question, just to increase the chance to get more answers!?

Comment: What kind of English dialect is this? Sounds like kaka to me :)

Comment: @Andreas_D I think you're too polite :)

Comment: @eugener - I reached my 10k rep today, I have to be polite :-))

Comment: @Andreas_D One has nothing to with another IMO :)

Comment: Please post any error messages or a better description of what happens when you "execute" the jar file. Are you using `java -jar yourfile.jar`? Is there an error at the command prompt? Does any of your Swing UI appear? Also, keep in mind that you're appealing to busy, professional software developers. Show respect through the use of proper English grammar and spelling.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell without seeing some code or error/exception stack traces. The most typical cause for problems of this kind are incomplete classpaths. Maybe your database driver class is missing on the classpath.

Some things you might check:

- Do you get some sort of error?
- Is the jar executable? If yes - that's the case when you start the application with something like `java -jar path/to/myjar.jar` - the classpath *must* be specified in the jar files Manifest, any `-cp` value is simply ignored.

---

Looking at your last comment, I'm pretty sure, that this is a classpath problem. The database driver usually resides in a different jar file and if the classpath entry in your manifest.mf file is blank, then the driver can't be loaded. This *should* result in an exception but maybe this is catched somewhere.

Solution #1 - edit the manifest.mf file and add all required libraries according to this [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html):

```
Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name
```

Solution #2 - don't start the application with the `-jar` option but use the standard way:

```
java -cp yourLib.jar;database-driver.jar your.application.Main
```

(all library entries have to be given with a correct relative or absolute file path)

Comment: no i dont get any type of error.
the jar file is executable. i tried to extract the contents of .jar file and tried to open the manifest.mf file in the META-INF folder through notepad++. the field under the classpath column is empty.
see i tell u the exact problem,
when i double click on my .jar file, the main frame window appears as it should be. now dere is a button on the main frame that searches for word match in database and displays its meaning upon clicking it, bt the meaning is not shown. dis is probably due to the fact that .jar file is unable to connect with mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

just copy the  database driver into C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\ext  and then run the jar file.